# How to prevent child component from updating parent component?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How to prevent this angularjs child component from updating its parent component?  In the code below, the instant I update the form in the modal, it updates the parent model as well.  This prevents the "cancel" button from working properly.

[Here's the plunker showing the issue.](https://plnkr.co/edit/ubWih2NLQ4dFjaSig5kj?p=preview)

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.1.118/styles/kendo.common.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.1.118/styles/kendo.bootstrap.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.css" />


  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.angularjs.org/1.5.8/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.1.118/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular-animate.js"></script>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/2.5.0/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>

  <script id="documents-template" type="text/ng-template">
    <button id="openDetails" name="openDetails" ng-click="model.openDetails(1)" class="btn btn-default">Open Details</button>
  <pre>{{ model | json }}</pre>
  </script>

  <script id="details-template" type="text/ng-template">
    <div class="modal-body">
      <label>Name To Edit</label>
      <input ng-model="model.document.title">
      <br>
      <label>Value To Edit</label>
      <input ng-model="model.document.fileName">
      <br>
      <button class="btn btn-success" type="button" ng-click="model.save()">Save Changes</button>
      <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" ng-click="model.cancel()">Cancel</button>
    </div>
    <pre>{{ model | json }}</pre>
  </script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<div ng-app="app">

  <documents-component></documents-component>


</div>

</body>

</html>
```

**script.js**

```
console.clear();

function documentController($uibModal, TransactionFactory) {
  var model = this;
  model.transaction = TransactionFactory;

  model.openDetails = function(id) {
    $uibModal.open({
      animation: true,
      component: 'detailsComponent',
      resolve: {
        document: function () {
          return model.transaction.documents[id - 1];
        }
      }
    }).result.then(function(result) {
      console.log("Save result was:", result);
    }, function(reason) {
      console.log("Dimissed reason was:", reason);
    });
  };
}

function detailsController() {
  var model = this;
  model.document = model.resolve.document;
  console.log("model.document", model.document);
  model.save = function() {
    console.log("saved was clicked. Passing back:", model.document);
    model.modalInstance.close(model.document);
  };
  model.cancel = function() {
    model.modalInstance.dismiss("cancel");
  };
}

var app = angular.module("app", ["kendo.directives", "ngAnimate", "ui.bootstrap"]);

app.factory('TransactionFactory', function() {

  var doc1 = { id:1, title: "Doc1", fileName: "Doc1.pdf" }
  var doc2 = { id:2, title: "Doc2", fileName: "Doc2.pdf" }
  var doc3 = { id:3, title: "Doc3", fileName: "Doc3.pdf" }
  var doc4 = { id:4, title: "Doc4", fileName: "Doc4.pdf" }
  var dummyData = [doc1, doc2, doc3, doc4];

  console.log("dummyData:", dummyData);

  return {
    documents: dummyData
  };
});

app.component("documentsComponent", {
    template: $("#documents-template").html(),
    controllerAs: "model",
    controller: ["$uibModal", "TransactionFactory", documentController]
});

app.component("detailsComponent", {
    template: $("#details-template").html(),
    bindings: {
      modalInstance: "<",
      resolve: '<'
    },
    controllerAs: "model",
    controller: [detailsController]
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tried a few changes... basically **passing a copy** of the required object and only saving (assigning) it when the Save Changes button is clicked.

Your function should be:

```
model.openDetails = function(id) {
$uibModal.open({
  animation: true,
  component: 'detailsComponent',
  resolve: {
    document: function () {
      return angular.copy( model.transaction.documents[id - 1] );
    }
  }
}).result.then(function(result) {
  console.log("Save result was:", result);
  model.transaction.documents[id - 1] = result ;

}, function(reason) {
  console.log("Dimissed reason was:", reason);
});
```

[Try it out](https://plnkr.co/edit/0KU7HJWnFvy1Rfi9js0i?p=preview)

Comment: I didn't seem to need the extra `}).resolve: {}` piece of code - was that necessary for anything specific?

Comment: My mistake, I pasted it in parts and mistakenly did the resolve twice. Edited it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that in both components you're using reference to the same object with data. So when you edit data in modal you actually edit original object with data which is used also by parent component. Solution is to pass copy of object to your modal.

Answer (score 1):

Refer to the updated plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/cvR8i883Q1ZlPPTA8Ryk?p=preview. you need to pass a copy of object.

```
function detailsController() {
    var model = this;
    model.document = angular.copy(model.resolve.document);
    console.log("model.document", model.document);
    model.save = function() {
        console.log("saved was clicked. Passing back:", model.document);
        model.modalInstance.close(model.document);
    };
    model.cancel = function() {
        model.modalInstance.dismiss("cancel");
    };
}
```